# Using Thread.sleep() for pausing and resuming app

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

Hi,
In my app im trying to use Thread.sleep(100) to pause my thread, while its backgrounded in order to use less cpu, but it freezes when I open it back up.
I realized that `onResume` is not being called when I reopen the app.

Any ideas why?

```
public void onPause() {
        pause = true;
        Log.d("mSTATE","THREADPAUSE");
    }

public void onResume() {
    pause = false;
        running = true;
       Log.d("mSTATE","THREADRESUME");
    }
public void run() {

    while(running){
         while(pause && running){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
         }

         while (!pause && running) {
             Canvas c = null;
             try {
                 c = sHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                 synchronized (sHolder) {
                     doDraw(c);
                     powerUps();
                 }
             } finally {
                 if (c != null) {
                     sHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                 }
             }
         }
    }
         Log.d("mState","EndofRun");              
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put your thread to sleep you are also blocking the UI thread thus leading to freezing of your application.

You need to check the Threads in Android way for the best performance.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Comment: Surface View thread is an UI thread.If you interrupt it with another thread etc you just freeze the UI.

Comment: how would you recomend i implement the pause and resume?